# cpuprofile and memprofile in golang testing

Tags: testing, go, memprof

I tried the command **go test -cpuprofile cpu.out** on a **GO test file** and it resulted in a file **cpu.out** which is full of many 64 bit numbers. It doesn't make any sense to me. What did the command do and what information can get I extract from cpu.out file?

Similarly **go test -memprofile mem.out** generated a **mem.out** file which also seems to make no sense to me. Help me out.

I have attached both the files.

[cpu.out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16F4aE0W_m6S3hZVVRGZEVPeXM) and [mem.out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16F4aE0W_m6UjhpdVdJWTJTNGM)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the output profiles in coordination with the `go tool` e.g.:

```
go tool pprof testbin.test cpu.out
```

I'd recommend some `func Benchmark*(b *testing.B)` implementations for functionality you're interesting in profiling.

Once in the tool try `top10`:

```
Welcome to pprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(pprof) top10
```

More information: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs